# Gaussian Mixture Model cross-validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, testing, scikit-learn

I'd like to cross-validate my gaussian mixture model. Currently I use sklearn's `cross_validation` method as below.

```
clf = GaussianMixture(n_components=len(np.unique(y)), covariance_type='full')
cv_ortho = cross_validate(clf, parameters_train, y, cv=10, n_jobs=-1, scoring=scorer)
```

I see that cross_validation is training my classifier with `y_train` making it a supervised classifier.

```
try:
    if y_train is None:
        estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    else:
        estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
```

However, I wanted to cross-validate an unsupervised classifier `clf.fit(parameters_train)`. I understand that the classifier then assigns its own class labels. Since, I have two distinguished clusters (see image) and `y` I can decipher the corresponding labels. Then cross-validate. Is there a routine in `sklearn` which does this?

A routine similar to this example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm_covariances.html

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that typical cross-validation is not something that either makes sense or has been used for unsupervised learning (see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261269/how-to-perform-validation-on-unsupervised-learning) of Cross Validated Stack Exchange).

#### Why it does not make sense?

In the strict case, cross validation requires some ground truth about the "correct" labels or values provided by the model. Typically denoted as the `y` in scikit-learn methods definition.
When you are training in an *unsupervised* way the sheer notion of the training not being supervised means that there are no `y` labels; no *true labels*, no "ground truth".
This is raised also in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/79079/163208) of a question on [evaluation of unsupervised learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79028/performance-metrics-to-evaluate-unsupervised-learning) (which is a broader term than cross-validation).